# Add a count of Business Days column when run. Counting Date in table to today

Tags: sql, date, ssms, days

```
SELECT
    FullDate,
    DATEDIFF(dd, Fulldate, @Today) 
FROM
    (SELECT  
         [DateKey],
         [FullDate],
         [DayOfWeekName],
         [DayOfWeekAbbreviation],
         [IsWeekday],
         [IsUSCivilHoliday],
         CASE 
             WHEN IsWeekday = 'y' AND IsUSCivilHoliday = 'n' 
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 
         END AS BusinessDay
     FROM 
         [ARCUSYM000].[dbo].[dimDate]
     WHERE
         FullDate > CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE() - 200, 110) 
         AND FullDate <= CONVERT(varchar(20), GETDATE(), 110)) x
GROUP BY
    FullDate
```

My problem is that I can't figure out a way to get only the business days.

I have a column `BusinessDay` that marks a business day or not. For each row in the data, I want to add how many business days till the current date. DateAdd like I have counts every day. Can anyone recommend a good way to do this?

```
Full Date | Business days till current date
```

Those are the two columns I need. Hope this makes sense

Example of what I need :

```
FullDate    BusinessDays
------------------------
2024-02-01      4
2024-02-02      3
2024-02-03      3
2024-02-04      3
2024-02-05      2
2024-02-06      1
2024-02-07      0
```

```
FullDate    DayOfWeekName   DayOfWeekAbbreviation   IsWeekday   IsUSCivilHoliday    BusinessDay
2024-01-29           MONDAY        MON                  Y         N                     1
2024-01-30           TUESDAY       TUE                  Y         N                     1
2024-01-31          WEDNESDAY       WED                 Y         N                     1
2024-02-01          THURSDAY        THU                 Y         N                     1
2024-02-02           FRIDAY         FRI                 Y         N                     1
2024-02-03          SATURDAY        SAT                 N         N                    0
2024-02-04           SUNDAY         SUN                 N         N                     0
2024-02-05           MONDAY         MON                 Y         N                     1
2024-02-06          TUESDAY         TUE                 Y         N                     1
2024-02-07         WEDNESDAY        WED                 Y         N                     1
```

Comment: you need to provide the original data that produces that end result  ideally woth create table

Comment: I added a picture of the data i'm working with for last 10 days..
Mainly looking for the function that can count based on how many 1's are in between the date and current date I feel.

Comment: images are not allowed in SO see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Which dbms are you using? The above query is product specific in several ways.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: To create a nice Markdown table of your data, do a google search for "convert data to markdown table" or some such, you'll get several links to paste your data and create a nice markdown table like [this link](https://thisdavej.com/copy-table-in-excel-and-paste-as-a-markdown-table/)

Comment: A proper table is so easy to make, when editing just highlight the text and click `{}`.

Comment: Quite why `FullDate` is a `varchar` column instead of `date` is another question....

Comment: I can of course convert. I am just looking for the function that would compare each row date to the current date and count the business days.